# Using powdered salt vs regular

Tags: baking, cookies

While tasting some chocolate chip cookies I made, I noticed a salt taste in one bite and I wondered; if the salt was powdered, could it be incorporated better? 
Would this change the taste? 
Would there be any chemical changes in the baking process?

Comment: You mean differance between rock salt and powder salt?

Comment: Do you measure you salt by weight or volume? If by volume you may need to adjust the quantity as different crystals will pack differently

Answer (score 2):

In cookies ordinary sized salt crystals should always be dissolved and evenly distributed by the mixing process, if you are hitting salty areas the batter may not have been mixed enough or it's possible there were clumps of salt. Mix the flour, salt and leavening agents together before adding them, and break up any salt clumps with your fingers.